# Remove item from DropDownList by value using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have the following DropDownList.

```
@Html.DropDownList("AttractionsAvaiableAttractions", Model.AvaiableAttractions)
```

I use script to get access to this dropdownlist located id td element. How can I remove item from this dropdownlist **by value** not by selected item?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = document.getElementById('TimeTableAttractions');
            var rowLength = table.rows[0].length;
            var row = table.rows[0];
            for (var y = 1; y < row.cells.length; y++) {
                var $td = $(row.cells[y]).closest("td");
                var itemToRemove = 'Example';
                $td.find("[name^='AttractionsAvaiableAttractions']").Remove(itemToRemove);
            }   
        });
```

Comment: I don't use ID because this element repeats in next columns I use only names.

Comment: Dont include it in `Model.AvaiableAttractions` if you do not need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try,

```
var itemToRemove = 'Example';

$("[name='AttractionsAvaiableAttractions '] option[value='"+itemToRemove+"']").remove();
```

where AttractionsAvaiableAttractions is the name of your dropdown.

Please find the sample,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">     
            function removeItem() {
                $("[name='programminglanguages'] option[value='2']").remove();
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="ddlList" name="programminglanguages">
        <option value="www.codewithvijay.com">Code</option>
        <option value="2">C#</option>
        <option value="3">Java</option>
        <option value="4">Go</option>
        <option value="5">C++</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick='removeItem()' value="Click" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't use ID because this element repeats in next columns I use only names.

Comment: I have created a working sample with the same solution I have provided, which is working. Please try it out. Please don't forgot to add JQuery.

Comment: Before remove I must add .eq(0).remove(); Then it works. Thanks.